# Yield next business day in R

Tags: r, datetime, bizdays

I need to calculate next business day in R with two parameters today's date and a data.frame having list of dates which are holidays

I tried but it's yielding today's date only

```
> cal <- create.calendar("MyCalendar", holidays = as.timeDate(HolidayList$Holidays), weekdays=c("sunday"))
> following(Sys.Date(),'MyCalendar')
[1] "2019-03-20"
> adjust.next(Sys.Date(),'MyCalendar')
[1] "2019-03-20"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

offset function did the trick

```
> offset(Sys.Date(),1,'MyCalendar')
[1] "2019-03-21"
```

also `add.bizdays(dates, n, cal)` function works the same

```
> add.bizdays(Sys.Date(),3,'MyCalendar')
[1] "2019-03-25"
```